# calling xml file in selenium rc test cases

Tags: java, junit, selenium-rc

how can I integrate xml file into my selenium rc test cases? I want to grab information from the file and insert it into the web page and test it.
thanks, Nitin

Comment: most probably who will have to make use of a xml parser library like JBix as if you were developing a common java application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you can use org.w3c.dom.Document to read XML data into a Parameterized JUnit test.  You MUST use JUnit 4.11 or higher.  [Here is some sample code to get you started on reading the xml file.](https://gist.github.com/3186212#file-gistfile1-java)   [Here is an example of creating a Parameterized data provider.](https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate/blob/master/core/google/src/test/java/qa/webdriver/tests/GoogleTest.java)

To get that working, you will need to merge these 2 ideas.  I can't write your code for you, unfortunately.